# Given 2 point and a range from first point to the point that I have to find. How to find the point I have to find (on 3D Space)

Tags: c++, c, math, vector

I don't know how to find the third point that I have said.

However, I try to write code write this:

```
float extraX; // x of the third point
float extraY; // y of the third point
float extraZ; // z of the third point

void CalculateExtraPoint(float x1, float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2){
    float range = extraRange; //range from the first point to third point 
    float d_x = x1-x2; 
    float d_y = y1-y2;
    float d_z = z1-z2;
    distance1_2 = sqrt(pow(d_x,2)+pow(d_y,2)+pow(d_z,2));
    float temp = (range/distance1_2)+1;
    extraX = x2 + (temp*d_x);
    extraY = y2 + (temp*d_y);
    extraZ = z2 + (temp*d_z);
}
```

It come from vector equation, r=(x2,y2,z2) + (lambda)[x1-x2,y1-y2,z1-z2]. r is any point.

Is it correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As for your question: please provide a sample data set, like coordinates of 2 points in 3d, range, and expected result for such data. Minimum one data set, two or three would be nice to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

Slightly simpler, more convenient variant. Here it is more clear that we consider range from the first point:

```
float temp = range/distance1_2;
extraX = x1 + (temp*d_x);
extraY = y1 + (temp*d_y);
extraZ = z1 + (temp*d_z);
```